# É possível rodar um script automaticamente ao acessar uma determinada URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Não tenho acesso ao código desta página, mais gostaria de automatizar uma tarefa que executo em um site, a cada 2 horas.. já desenvolvi um script para isso, jogo ele no console e executo, até ai tudo certo.. porem quando a tarefa é executada ela da um reload na página e limpa o console. Tem como eu adicionar automaticamente um script no console quando acessar essa URL, ou alguma outra solução?

Comment: Talvez criando um plugin. Ja tentou?

Comment: Você poderia utilizar um Crontab pra realizar estas tarefas